# Is connecting to a DB2 database through Port 443 possible

Tags: networking, db2, port, db2-luw

The title says it all.

There is an odd request from the security team to make all necessary connections through port 443. This is not that difficult as most of the apps do this by default. NO OTHER PORTS MAY BE OPENED.

We have a new requirement to give devs access to a small database in our cloud. The database normally listens to port 50000 which they will not open to give the reporting team access.

The short-term solution is to onboard the team to a VPN so that they can get access on their desktops, long-term.... could I force fit DB2 to connect through port 443? I haven't been able to try it. I know its an odd requirement but at this point, I am curious if anyone has and the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should be doable. The port (or its name) is set in the [SVCENAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000273.html) configuration option. If SSL is used, the option is [SSL_SVCENAME](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0053615.html).

A quick test would be to change the configuration, restart Db2 and open up a connection to that port (telnet or Db2 client).

Note 1: HTTPS is usually on port 443, but if there is no web server it is ok.
Note 2: Root privileges are needed to set up and use such privileged ports.

Comment: Db2 would need root privileges or `setcap` to bind to a privileged port (<1024)

Comment: Im not the best networking guy, but do you havent to take SSL off that port prior to doing that?

Comment: Also, root access is not an issue.

Comment: So this ended up working fine. The main issue I kept hitting was that the db2 commands needed me to type out the filename as "C:\Program+Files..." to not escape, but would not restart properly. Once I moved the kdb to a more friendly names directory, the service started properly on port 443. Thanks for the help @data_henrik